# What, if any, immigration controls can be expected on a domestic flight within the UK?

Tags: visas, air-travel, uk, customs-and-immigration, domestic-travel

I'm a person who has overstayed their UK visa and wants to visit a solicitor to attempt to regularize my status in the country. Given that the solicitor is located in Scotland and I'm living in London, flying is the most convenient method of travel.

Would it be unwise to travel by plane between England and Scotland to visit him? What immigration checks are usually performed at UK airports for domestic flights?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69447/discussion-on-question-by-j-doe-what-if-any-immigration-controls-can-be-expec).

Comment: Is there really no solicitor based in London who can assist you?

Comment: Are you sure flying is the most convenient, especially in your situation? Train takes longer, about 4.5 hours, but goes city-center to city-center, and has no check-in or id requirements.

Comment: I had a referral to the one in Scotland and thus have now comfort and trust in visiting him.

Comment: @patricia, it may well not be, but that's what I'm trying to find out, after taking event into account.

Comment: Just get the train then you wont have to worry about showing ID whatsoever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the airlines which provides many domestic flights within the UK is Flybe. For such flights passengers must provide photo ID, see the list [here](https://www.flybe.com/checkin/id-requirements/) which includes a number of documents are not directly related to immigration status. So it would be difficult for them to check status even if they wished to.

> Domestic travel - all must be photographic unless otherwise stated
>   A valid passport
>   An expired passport (domestic flights only up to two years after expiry)
>   Valid EU or Swiss national identity card
>   Valid driving licence (Full or Provisional are accepted)
>   Valid armed forces identity card
>   Valid police warrant card/badge
>   Valid airport employees security identity pass
>   A child on parent’ s passport is an acceptable form of ID
>   CitizenCard or Civillian Card
>   Valid firearm certificate
>   Valid Government-issued identity card
>   NHS SMART card
>   Electoral identity card
>   NUS card (National Union of Students)
>   University/college ID card
>   Company ID card of nationally recognised company
>   Council issued bus pass
>   Pension book (the only acceptable form of non-photographic identification)
>   Young Scot card
>   Disabled badges which have a photograph of the holder
>   Certificate of Competency issued by the Government (domestic routes only, must be photographic)
>   VALIDATE UK PASS photographic proof of age cards

I assume other airlines have similar rules.

Arrivals at UK domestic terminals does not usually involve the National Border Agency, at least at the ones I have used.

Answer (score 7):

There will normally be no immigration checks at all when flying domestically, although at Heathrow and Gatwick you will be photographed at security.

At least at Heathrow and Stansted, Border Force officers occasionally perform spot checks after security, though with a domestic boarding pass you should not be asked for travel documents.

Comment: Yes, and if he gets asked for ID only the photo page of passport would be checked to confirm it's him and not his visa, unless someone is really looking to catch an overstayer on a domestic flight, which is highly improbable.